# Convergence of maximising points of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = \sup_{w \in \Omega} g(x,w)$, where $\Omega$ is compact and $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and $g$ is continuous. Since $\Omega$ is compact, $f(x) = \max_{w \in \Omega} g(x,w)$. For some $x$ let the function $W(x)$ return the point $w$ such that $f(x) = g(x,w)$ (assume $g$ is such that there is only one such point for all $x$). Now, if a sequence $x_k \rightarrow x$, then is it true that $W(x_k)$ converges to $W(x)$?

Comment: $W$ is not  a well defined function since the point where the maximum is attained is not unique.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy that's why I am assuming that $g$ is such that $W$ is well defined

Comment: @palongsag Is $g$ continuous? differentiable?

Comment: @OlivierRoche continuous. Sorry for missing that out, edited the question.